# Convert Resume from Photoshop to ??? to improve PDF quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, pdf, image-quality, file-format

I've made a huge mistake. I found a cool template for a resume that I liked and spent hours making it what I wanted in photoshop only to find out that saving as PDF makes all the text look blurry. I've tried converting the text layers to objects but it doesn't seemed to have helped. I have the entire adobe suite, is there anything that can be done? I don't know how to transfer PSD files to other apps. I tried with indesign but it shows up extremely blurry when I use the "place" function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you working in vector or raster?

Comment: If this is a resume *for* a designer being created *by* a designer, it should be done with InDesign or Illustrator. Reconstruct it entirely if necessary.

Comment: @Tetsujin vector I think? Since I still have the option to rasterize layers.

Comment: @Scott I'm not a designer, just and amateur photoshop user trying to make a nice looking resume. Is there any way to save the work done by transferring to a different program within adobe suite?

Comment: Not really, Andrew. There's no direct 1-1 conversion for many Photoshop files. You can *try* opening the .psd file with Illustrator. That **might** retain the live type. (InDesign won't convert anything) I hesitate to tell you what to do specifically if you aren't overly familiar with the tools. It almost *always* takes some "massaging" when trying to move from Photoshop to another app. Quite honestly, rebuilding it in InDesign is the optimum way to go if you have and are familiar with InDesign. These are professional-level tools so they can take some experience to use effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the image size under the image tab can help, but not by much. But still, it is better than not doing anything.

After that, change the anti-aliasing method from `None` to `Sharp`.
That usually take away the blur. I've used this trick before and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Much of any output quality will depend upon *specifics* regarding any canned template you've downloaded. It's entirely possible the resolution of such a template is below optimum settings. However, using Live Type Layers within Photoshop should generally yield good results provided any PDF job options are set accordingly (and the Photoshop file is high quality).

Overall, Photoshop is **not** the most wonderful of tools to use for a *resume*. Photoshop is an **image editor** not a type layout application. Sure you *can* do some layout with it, but in many instances you probably *shouldn't*. This is compounded if the the resume in question has **nothing** to do with a design career or related field.

## form vs function

A resume is to be used to convey *information* in the most easily ingested format. Often a screen reader or OCR application is used to process resumes. By getting too "artsy" with a resume you **can** create *problems* for potential employers. And one problem with your resume surely means no call back.

Even for a designer, using Photoshop to create a resume is ill advised. It is simply *not* the correct tool. And rest assured, potential employers *can* see what app generated a PDF. Many employers may frown heavily if they discover Photoshop was used for your resume. This shows a basic misunderstanding of what tool to use for what job.

---

In any event, there is no 1:1 conversion from Photoshop to any other application. In all most every instance objects or elements may need to be rebuilt in another application because there's no direct conversion from Photoshop.

Illustrator *may* allow one to retain any live type from Photoshop by merely *opening* the .psd file with Illustrator and choosing the correct options to "create layers". Using Illustrator can be okay for a resume but be very careful to avoid too many linked/placed raster elements and too much "art" overall.

The **optimum** method would be to generate your resume in InDesign if you have it and are familiar with it.

---

Text is preferred for resumes... even using Microsoft Word is generally better than using Photoshop for a resume. Photoshop is **not** the "be-all-end-all" and using it can, in some cases, be a *detriment* not a benefit.